# Google App Engine SocketTimeout Exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Can someone help with this exception?

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=CODE&redirect_uri=https:REDIRECT_URI
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the API.

Check here:

https://developers.facebook.com/live_status